# proper formatting printing the length of items in a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

My code seems to be working, but I have having trouble with the print statement, which I will eventually write out to a CSV.  I am able to get the print to work for the first two items, but when I try to add the len part as the third thing to print, it get an error "'str' object is not callable".  When I print the len part by itself, it seems to work fine.  Any insight as to what I am doing wrong to print all together?

```
    inFile = open(file.txt,'r')
    reader = csv.reader(inFile)
    allrows = list(reader)
    dd = defaultdict(OrderedDict)
    ids = OrderedDict()

    output = {}
    iterallrows = iter(allrows)
    next(iterallrows)
    for row in iterallrows:
        id_ = row[2]
        name = row[3]
        dd[id_][name] = None
        ids[id_] = None
        print('{} {} {}'.format(id_,','.join(dd[id_],','(len(dd[id_])))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this:

```
[...],','(...)[...]
```

This attempts to treat `','` as a function, which it is not. Put a comma between all arguments to a function.